# How do I prevent Google Maps from reinitializing after a geocode lookup?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps Javascript API v.3.  Below is the javascript that I've written.  The goal is to initialize a map, and then do an address lookup via the Google maps geocoder, use that lat long to re-center the map, and set a marker down.  I think I've got most of it working, except that after I recenter the map and place a marker, the page fires another onLoad event which causes the initialize() function to run again and resets all of my variables.  After staring at this code for half a day, I'm not sure what is causing the extra onLoad event.  What is causing it?

I am also new to writing javascript and working with Google maps, so I'm happy for other pointers on code quality.  I know that I've tried to scope several variables globally and I'm not sure that I've done it correctly.

Here is the code (note: I plan on replacing the setTimeout function eventually, but I still haven't gotten the knack of programming asynch calls yet...I figured I will tackle that next).

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
               var map;
               var geocoder;
               var marker;
               var latlng;
               function initialize() {
                   geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                   var mapOptions = {
                                     center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.606, -122.314),
                                     zoom: 12
                                    };
                   if (this.map == null){
                      this.map = new               google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
                                        }
                   }
                                    
  
  function checkResponse(results, response){
       if (response == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
           this.latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
           this.map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
           this.marker = new google.maps.marker({                                                                 map: map,                                                                   position: results[0].geometry.location});
                                        }
        else {
           alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + response);
             }

        }
                                    
function searchAddress(){
     var address = document.getElementById('address1').value;
     var state = document.getElementById('state1').value;
     var zip = document.getElementById('zip1').value;
     var addressInput = address + ',' + state + ',' + zip;

  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': addressInput}, function(results, status) {
  //ToDo remove this setTimeout function and replace it with a callback
        setTimeout(checkResponse(results, status), 3000);
  });
    }
              
                                    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
                                        </script>
```

Comment: Your code as posted only has one onload event (and no markers, javascript is case sensitive and google.maps.marker is not the same as [google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker)) - [jsfiddle with marker](http://jsfiddle.net/fuy0gt7k/1/)

Comment: The code actually shouldn't trigger any onLoad events, it should only be executed when the page has an onLoad event.  What I'm trying to determine is why, after executing the function searchAddress, does the page send another onLoad event?  This event triggers the initialize function which resets all of the changes I previously had made to the map.

Also thank you for bringing my attention to Javascript being case-sensitive; that fixed one bug I was working on.

Comment: How are you executing the `searchAddress` function?  The posted code never calls it.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue you are trying to solve.  I can **guess** that it is an onsubmit function for a form and is not returning false, causing the page to be reloaded in the browser.

Comment: It turns out that you are correct; I needed to add "return false" to the onClick form.

I'll be sure to include the HTML/CSS in the future.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When using a javascript function as the onsubmit function for a form, you must return false from the function if you don't want the page reloaded from the server.